# Finding parametrization

Tags: calculus, parameter-estimation, parametrization

The excercise: Find a parameterization of the cutting curve between the surfaces. The parameterization must be such that y (t) = ksin (t) for a positive constant k, and so that the cutting curve is traversed counterclockwise as seen from above.

The equations:
$$-3x^2+5z=1\qquad \text{og} \qquad 8x^2+7y^2=5$$

Until now I thought that I can start with working on the second equation. That is what I got:
$$\frac85 x^2+\frac75 y^2=1$$

So this clearly is a equation for an ellipse. $X = a\cos(t)$ and $y = b\sin(t)$ when parameterized. So I thought that
$a = b = \sqrt{5}$.

But it isn't the right answer. I don't quite understand what am I supposed to do with the numerators.

Comment: HINT: $\frac{a}{b}x^{2}=\frac{x^{2}}{b/a}=\frac{x^{2}}{(\sqrt{b/a})^{2}}$

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand it!